# (SharePoint) How do I add a Calendar app part from a subsite to a parent site?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

Basically like the title states, I have a subsite with a Calendar App part and would like to add it onto the landing page of my root site.

I've tried using SharePoint Designer and just copying and pasting out the  section but received an error saying the list does not exist.

I'm also unable to get it to work from saving the web part as a file and then uploading into my root site.

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe if you ask at http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/ you will find better answer.

Comment: Also, you could look for a solution using this jQuery library http://spservices.codeplex.com/ , with this library you can access the calendar data from other site using sharepoint webservices.

Comment: I appreciate the comment, I'll make a post over there shortly and take a look into that library. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Most web parts are specific to the subsite on which they are displayed.  You cannot connect a calendar web part on a parent site out of the box.  You'll need to use either a content query web part or build a custom calendar web part.   The content query web part will display your items in a list, so if you want a calendar view, you'll either need to heavily format the underlying xsl or go with the custom web part.